# Batch Coding Menu Option to Go Back

Tags: batch-file, menu, label

I'm fairly new to coding, and I've been told to start with batch files. I'm attempting to make a text based game that prompts the user to choose between a few options to progress through the story. I've got the basic idea down, but I ran into some trouble with making a menu. I've done some research on here, and have searched other sites, but can't seem to make heads or tails of some of the answers to similar questions. Most of the answers write out code that I assume would work, but I need to know the WHY behind these answers, and I haven't really found any answers that I could understand.

TLDR; I need to make a menu for a text based game, that allows the user to return the label they left off on.

What I have so far:

```
:MainMenu
cls
echo Input Options:
echo.
echo ::1) View Storyline Changes
echo ::2) Restart Test
echo ::3) Resume Test
echo ::4) Help
echo ::5) Quit
echo.
set /p input=Input:
if "%input%" == "1" goto StorylineChanges
if "%input%" == "2" goto Rst
if "%input%" == "3" goto ResumeTest
if "%input%" == "4" goto HelpScrn
if "%input%" == "5" exit

:StorylineChanges
cls
echo Unimportant to test.
echo.
echo                                        Input "m" to go back
echo.
set /p input=Input: 
if "%input%" == "m" goto Main Menu
if "%input%" == " " goto WrongInputStorylineChanges

:Rst
cls
goto :StartTest
echo off

:ResumeTest
cls
REM ***THIS IS WHERE I NEED HELP ***
pause >nul
goto StartTest
```

As you can probably immediately tell, I BARELY have a grasp on basic commands, so please keep that in mind if you provide an answer. I'd really appreciate any help you guys could give me. Thanks so much.

Comment: Read up on the Choice command, _`Choice /?` at the Command prompt_. When you have known menu items, it makes life a whole lot easier. Oh and it appears you have a `goto Main Menu`, but the label reads, `MainMenu`

Comment: I'm not sure who indicated that batch would be a good place to start learning programming, but I think python is a much better place. Esp for this sort of thing (batch is better when dealing with files or utilities)

Comment: See the `call` command. Then batch will act like programming languages as they don't use `goto`. Functions return to where they left off.

Comment: Please take the [tour], read [Ask] and [MCVE].  What you already have there for code is close.  Your "THIS IS WHERE I NEED HELP" comment isn't very helpful though.  What exactly do you need help with?  A quick read of the script, seems to indicate you need help elsewhere as well, I am assuming you've only tested the happy paths up to this point.  What happens if the user mistypes the response to the menu prompt?  You're going to have to store the last label the user visited or you'll never get back to it.  Does this have to survive exiting the script as well as returning to main menu?

Comment: Research [Spaghetti code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spaghetti_code). Where you need help is just jumping to yet another `goto`. The code can only get worse with this excessive use of `goto`.

Comment: That's all very helpful everyone, thank you. Now, is it considered "neater" code to use a colon before the label when using a `goto` or `call` command, like `goto :MainMenu` or `goto MainMenu`? Or is it just personal preference? I researched Spaghetti code, and that certainly explains why I'm having difficulty. I think my problems can be solved if I develop a better understanding of how to properly structure code. @Monacraft I read that Python, Java, and C are all great beginner languages. For learning how to make the code really _flow_, which of those would you recommend as a starting point?

Comment: @Valiant_Squirrel Personally, I'd recommend staying away from Java to start with. Python is better for people with no programming experience (and very little idea of what they are walking into). Whenever I've had to teach highschoolers (and even some of my uni-mates) it's always what I start with. I know most Uni-courses will start with C, but if it is your first time I'd learn python for more then a month, then go onto a C (that just gives you time to get used to programming). As for flow, obviously a C-language would be best, but Python is still pretty good, so the choice is yours :)

Comment: Basic is the language that teaches logic. The other languages you do things to keep the CPU happy. Basic keeps this from you allowing you to focus on your program's structure. There are two Basics built into Windows and one in Office. See for VBScript http://download.microsoft.com/download/winscript56/Install/5.6/W982KMeXP/EN-US/scrdoc56en.exe. Basic follows the rules of algebra that you learnt in school, the other languages are focused on CPUs.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot unravel the spaghetti code, but I can give an example
detailing how to go back to the menu as the title asks.

```
@echo off

:MainMenu
cls
echo Input Options:
echo.
echo ::1) View Storyline Changes
echo ::2) Restart Test
echo ::3) Resume Test
echo ::4) Help
echo ::5) Quit
echo.
set /p input=Input:
if "%input%" == "1" call :StorylineChanges
if "%input%" == "2" call :Rst
if "%input%" == "3" call :ResumeTest
if "%input%" == "4" call :HelpScrn
if "%input%" == "5" exit /b 0
goto :MainMenu

:StorylineChanges
echo Use "goto :eof" to exit script or exit called label.
pause
goto :eof

:Rst
echo Use "exit /b" to exit script or exit called label with a errorlevel.
pause
exit /b 0

:ResumeTest
>&2 echo Exit called label with errorlevel 1. This line is to stderr.
pause
exit /b 1

:HelpScrn
echo Help. Exit with implicit 0.
pause
exit /b
```

The above uses `call` to access each label. Exit of a called label
returns back to the point of the call. The menu is in a loop so it keeps
showing until you input `5` to exit the script.

I added pauses into the labels so you could see the messages before `clr`
is called.